# Allow multiple selections on Person or Group field

Tags: content-type, column, metadata, spfield, provisioning

In SharePoint 2013 on-premise I am  trying to create a Person or Group field to use it in a content type. My problem with the field is that I cannot select more than 1 person. I have been googling a lot, and all posts say that it should be sufficient to set Mult="TRUE", and Type="UserMulti". I have done it, and tested it several times, it doesn't work. This is how my XML looks like:

```
  <Field ID="{7BDBB321-E55F-55G6-1082-61029C0997G1}" 
         StaticName="xxx_test"
         Name="xxx_test"
         DisplayName="Test Delete"
         Group="XXX"
         Type="UserMulti"  
         List="UserInfo" 
         Required="FALSE" 
         EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" 
         ShowField="ImnName" 
         UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" 
         UserSelectionScope="0" 
         Mult="TRUE" 
         Sortable="FALSE"  />
```

Please advice.

Comment: Deploy your solution and check the settings for the field. Is "Allow multiple selections" set to Yes? If not, your solution may not be deploying correctly.

Comment: It's set to no. I'll inspect my script for deploying fields. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I am using powershell to create fields: 

$FieldCollection = $site.RootWeb.Fields
$FieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml($FieldXmlElement.OuterXml)

can't see the problem with that. All other properties gets set correctly.

Comment: Was your field deployed previously ? You could try to add Overwrite="TRUE" to overwrite the field definition

Comment: I deleted the field completely and re deployed, and tried it on another site collection also. "Ghosting" is not the problem. The problem is in my xml and powershell, but I have not yet found what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all fields properties that have a return type of boolean, are set binarily (i.e. 1 = true, 0 = false). I would recommend looking at the return types of each of the properties you are trying to set on MSDN, [SP Field Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_properties.aspx).

It looks to me as though all your Boolean values are being incorrectly set. Set thusly;

```
<Field ID="{7BDBB321-E55F-55G6-1082-61029C0997G1}" 
     StaticName="xxx_test"
     Name="xxx_test"
     DisplayName="Test Delete"
     Group="XXX"
     Type="UserMulti"  
     List="UserInfo" 
     Required="0" 
     EnforceUniqueValues="0" 
     ShowField="ImnName" 
     UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" 
     UserSelectionScope="0" 
     Mult="1" 
     Sortable="1"  />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That was a good idea, but sadly didn't do the trick.

Comment: If you have the code that you are using to process your XML, that may be helpful. It may well be an issue with your code rather than the XML. Doing this myself, it was written all in PowerShell for instance.

Comment: I am using AddFieldAsXml, and adding the xml;

$FieldCollection = $site.RootWeb.Fields $FieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml($FieldXmlElement.OuterXml)